# Virtual Folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to utilise mod_rewrite allowing me to use domain.com/d4k1d to give the same effect as domain.com/link.php?link=d4k1d

At the moment I have this in my .htaccess although this seems to give me 404 errors.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[0-9]+)/ link.php?link=$1
```

I'm not too familiar with mod_rewrite etc. so I don't know where to go with this :S.

Comment: That may be the first time I've seen [a-z] written out by hand :)

Comment: But just think of the joy in discovering the use of [a-z]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all of the letters inside of the character class (which can also be simplified).  Your current rule only allows for a letter followed by one or more numbers:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /([a-z0-9]+)/ link.php?link=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the leading slash because it's stripped from the URI by apache before being used in rules that are in an htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /link.php?link=$1 [L]
```